# Is it possible to utilize custom SQL for a single-post.php?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to utilize custom SQL in the single-page.php file to return the desired single post's data?

For my purposes, there are data manipulations in the $querystr that are not easily reproducible using php and are easily achieved with simple SQL.

If I put the below code in a single-page.php file, I currently have the entire results set with one row per post. I want to pull only the row/record/post that is relevant to the page a user clicked on.

```
<?php

 $querystr = "
    SELECT custom_sql_column_name_here
    FROM custom_sql_example_table
 ";
 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
?>
 <?php if ($pageposts): ?>
  <?php global $post; ?>
  <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <p><?php the_field('custom_sql_column_name_here'); ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Is there a way to use the ID from the post a users wants and somewhere in the $pageposts or setup_postdata($post) to set a condition for the ID desired?

I am only interested in knowing if it is possible and would prefer not to know of commonly accepted "*right*" ways of pulling single-page post data with php that I already use now.

Comment: The right way would be to use a filter on the main query sql, but you are apparently not interested in that!

Comment: I'm not sure how you got the impression I wouldn't be interested in adding a filter to the main query sql. In fact, I'm very interested. Exactly how would I do that though?

Let's say there are 10 posts on my page and a user clicks a link to one of those posts. Without hard coding a condition in the main query sql, how do I add a condition for the post the user wants? Is there a variable that can penetrate the $querystr for the expected post? If this is a way to accomplish this, I'd love to know more details!

Comment: "I am only interested in knowing if it is possible".

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the ID of the requested post within the template, [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) will give you that.

If you want to modify the main query SQL *before* it's executed, there are [a number of filters that let you directly modify the SQL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#WP_Query_Filters).

Comment: Excellent! I'll take a closer look at these tonight.

Comment: This works darn near perfectly! Adding <?php if ($post->ID = get_queried_object_id()) echo $post->ID;?> gives me what I'm looking for. Now I just have to figure out how to not let the echo $post->ID not repeat for each piece of the array...